# I'm unable to connect mqtt mesage to broker installed in Ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, mqtt, mqtt.js

I'm unable to connect mqtt broker service installed in Ubuntu server from out side of the server even Port 1883 is allowed to access out side.
Whereas, I'm able to publish and subscribe in server machine.

What could be reason for inability to connect from outside?

msquitto.conf:

```
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd
port 1883
listener 9001
protocol websockets
```

Note: No logs reported in server machine while connecting through a client machine.

```html
const mqtt = require("mqtt")
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();

var clientId = `mqtt_${Math.random().toString(16).slice(3)}`
console.log(clientId);

var topic = 'temperature/floor1/room101'

var client =  mqtt.connect('mqtt://164.152.312.14:1883'
,{
         username: '******',
         password: '******'     
})


client.on('connect', ()=>{
    setInterval(()=>{
        if (client.connected==true){
        client.publish(topic, sendTemperature())
        console.log('Message sent!', sendTemperature())}
    }, 500)
})
function sendTemperature(){
    var t = {
      T: Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 10) + 5),
      Units: "C"
    };    
  return JSON.stringify(t);
    
  }
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73647130/edit) the question to answer: Is there anything in the logs when you try to connect? Exactly what error (from what client) do you seen when it fails to connect from a remote machine.

Comment: No logs recorded against connectivity. I'm trying to connect through mqtt browser and mqtt.js. It is not getting connected to server. ie connect event itself not happened in client.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the client code, at worst we might be able to suggest how to add some more error checking to show why it's failing to connect. As it is the question needs more details

Comment: The same client is working in local machine for the local machine broker and it is simple code with credentials option passed to connection. The problem that faced while broker moved to server. Hope it clarifies. Do we need to set any other configuration in server?

Comment: Please do as I asked and show us the code or we won't be able to help you.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are using the HiveMQ "MQTT Browser Client" which only supports websocket connections. With the config shown port `9001` will be listening for Websocket connections and port `1883` TCP connections (by the way `port` is depreciated). You say "1883 is allowed to access out side" which is confusing when you should be using `9001` for websockets?. I'd suggest enabling logging (`log_type all`), connecting locally (ensure something is logged) then attempting to connect remotely (if nothing is logged then you have a network/firewall configuration issue).

Comment: thanks hardillb for reply. I've added the snippet. Is that right approach? or you are asking to change ws instead of mqtt?

Comment: Please also confirm how you are running the code. If via browser then you will need to use websockets because browsers security model does not permit raw TCP connections (whereas node etc does).

Comment: I'm running atm in vscode ie using node runtime because I'm trying to publish the data to the server broker, But I agree the point that you are mentioning might be applicable in subscriber end. I'm facing problem in publishing data to a broker in server from a client machine - node runtime.

Comment: OK - Hopefully it's just a typo in your question but `164.152.312.14` is not a valid IP (`312` > `255`). I can't really say more than that without more info (previously suggested how to narrow down the issue).

Comment: Oops, It is invalid only and I have changed it from the actual one as IP is exposed to public site. I have enabled log_type all and port also got changed to figure out but it wasn't helpful. Anyway thanks. Let me check any other problem exists.

Comment: We tried to install it in another server with same configuration. Not sure what caused the issue. Now it is working for the port 1883 i.e publish and subscribe happening from clients system.
But, it is unfortunate web sockets are not working meaning web application in react is not able to receive the published data on a topic.
What could be the reason of it ( in Linux -ubuntu)?
Am I missing any configuration missing in the code snippet?

Comment: Really difficult to comment without a lot more info (this is probably a separate question). For instance you may be facing a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue. Maybe try accessing it from [here](http://www.hivemq.com/demos/websocket-client/) (assuming your broker is publicly accessible) and see what is logged (if anything).

Comment: Thanks Brits. It is not CORS. But there is problem in the constructor that we used in react to make connectivity. An alternate piece of code solved it. 
Cheers!!